# Can't find crate for `rayon`

Tags: rust, dependency-management, rust-cargo, rust-crates, rayon

I am trying to find the diameter of a BST using parallelization:

```
extern crate rayon;

use std::cmp::Ordering::*;
use std::ops::Index;
use rayon::prelude::*;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node<K> {
    left: Option<Box<Node<K>>>,
    right: Option<Box<Node<K>>>,
    key: K,
}

impl<K> Node<K> {
    fn new(k: K) -> Node<K> {
        Node {
            left: None,
            right: None,
            key: k,
        }
    }
}

impl<K: Ord> Node<K> {
    fn insert(&mut self, n: Node<K>) {
        match n.key.cmp(&self.key) {
            Less => {
                match self.left {
                    None => self.left = Some(Box::new(n)),
                    Some(ref mut l) => l.insert(n),
                }
            }
            Greater => {
                match self.right {
                    None => self.right = Some(Box::new(n)),
                    Some(ref mut r) => r.insert(n),
                }
            }
            _ => {}
        }
    }

    fn height(&self) -> u32 {
        let mut left_he = 1;
        if let Some(ref l) = self.left {
            left_he = 1 + l.height()
        }
        let mut right_he = 1;
        if let Some(ref r) = self.right {
            right_he = 1 + r.height()
        }
        if left_he > right_he {
            return left_he;
        }
        return right_he;
    }

    fn rec(&self) -> u32 {
        let mut le = 0;
        if let Some(ref l) = self.left {
            le = l.height()
        }
        let mut re = 0;
        if let Some(ref r) = self.right {
            re = r.height()
        }
        let hei = le + re + 1;
        let mut led = 0;
        let mut red = 0;

        let Some(ref l) = self.left;

        let Some(ref r) = self.right;

        rayon::join(|| led = l.rec(), || red = r.rec());

        let greater_diameter;
        if red > led {
            greater_diameter = red;
        } else {
            greater_diameter = led;
        }

        if hei > greater_diameter {
            return hei;
        }
        return greater_diameter;
    }

    fn print_recursive(nodes: Vec<&Self>) {
        let mut v: Vec<&Self> = vec![];
        for n in nodes {
            print!("1 ");
            match n.left {
                None => {}
                Some(ref l) => v.push(&*l),
            }
            match n.right {
                None => {}
                Some(ref r) => v.push(&*r),
            }
        }
        println!("");
        if v.len() > 0 {
            Node::print_recursive(v);
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct Bst<K> {
    root: Option<Box<Node<K>>>,
}
impl<K> Bst<K> {
    fn new() -> Bst<K> {
        Bst { root: None }
    }
}

impl<K: Ord> Bst<K> {
    fn insert(&mut self, k: K) {
        match self.root {
            None => self.root = Some(Box::new(Node::new(k))),
            Some(ref mut r) => r.insert(Node::new(k)),
        }
    }

    fn rec(&self) -> u32 {
        match self.root {
            None => 0,
            Some(ref r) => r.rec(),
        }
    }

    fn print(&self) {
        match self.root {
            None => {}
            Some(ref r) => Node::print_recursive(vec![&*r]),
        };
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut bst1 = Bst::new();

    bst1.insert(20);
    bst1.insert(21);
    bst1.insert(22);
    bst1.insert(23);
    bst1.insert(24);
    bst1.insert(25);
    bst1.insert(19);
    bst1.insert(18);
    bst1.insert(17);
    bst1.insert(16);
    bst1.insert(15);
    bst1.insert(14);
    bst1.print();

    println!("{}", bst1.rec());
}
```

When I compile (`rustc code.rs`), it shows

```
error: can't find crate for `rayon` [E0463]
```

My Rust version is `rustc 1.8.0 (db2939409 2016-04-11)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot just use an external dependency without telling the compiler where to find it. The easiest way of doing that is to create a `Cargo.toml` file and then use `cargo build` to compile your project instead of `rustc` directly.

To create the `Cargo.toml` file, you can just go into the project directory and type:

```
cargo init --bin
```

This will do two things:

1. Create the file `src/main.rs`. You should put your code in here.
2. Create a `Cargo.toml` file, which is used by Cargo for storing dependencies and other build information

You can then edit `Cargo.toml` to add the `rayon` dependency. The [crates.io page for rayon](https://crates.io/crates/rayon) gives you the exact information which you can just paste in there. When you are done, it should look something like this:

```
[package]
name = "foo"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["singh <singh@singh.com>"]

[dependencies]
rayon = "0.3.1"
```

Once you have this in place, you can build the project with:

```
cargo build
```

Or run with:

```
cargo run
```

You can get more information in the [Cargo guide](http://doc.crates.io/guide.html).

Comment: They'd also need to move code.rs into src/lib.rs, right?